# how to get current bloc config from hook_theme in drupal 8?

Tags: blocks, 8

i have created a plugin block and call the hook theme on build()

```
$output[] = [ '#theme' => 'amu_news' ];
```

from this hook_theme

```
function amu_news_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
```

i would need to access to the block form config values .

what object and method can use?

Comment: In amu_news_theme define the amu_news theme entry, and for whatever you want to do use the template_preprocess_amu_news_theme

Comment: can u tell me more ?

Comment: i have ended up doing the bloc config logic in bloc build()